# Add/summarize range of columns using the Calculate Field tool

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator

Let's say I have a dataset with multiple columns that I would like to add and the sum value will be stored in the `Total` column. These columns range from `Field3` to `Field141` in sequential order. Now I can add them by clicking them one by one in the Calculate Field tool but that would be tedious. Is there a way I can define a range like this `Total = !Field3! + (!Field4!:!Field141!)` or something similar using `Python` in the calculate field tool?

If not then how can I do this in the Python console window in ArcGIS Pro 3.1? (I am not a Python user so I'm hoping for sample code in the answer.)

The whole idea is to avoid typing each and every column.

Comment: Is it always field 3 to field 141? Or could it for example be such that field 99 be missing?

Comment: CalculateField is not the right tool for this. A DA UpdateCursor is the right solution.

Comment: Do it in Excel,  pragmatic approach, unless it is repeating task.

Comment: @Hornbydd yes, there are no spaces between `Field` and `number` in any of those column names.

Comment: @FelixIP I would prefer a Python solution probably in the console window as I am trying to learn Python and using it more in Pro, thank you.

Comment: @Vince can you please explain it in an answer as it'll help me learn, thank you.

Comment: If you are trying to learn Python, this is not the task to start with, especially with CalculateField. If you rewrite the Question to ask about a DA UpdateCursor, then you need to include code using a DA UpdateCursor. Try it first with two columns, then three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some code that works in ArcGIS Desktop, you should be able to get it to work in ArcGIS Pro with a bit of effort:

```
# get the names of all the fields that start with 'Field'
AllFieldNames = [Field.name for Field in arcpy.ListFields(YourFeatureClass,'Field*')]

# get an update cursor with only the columns you need
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(YourFeatureClass, ['total'] + AllFieldNames) as uCur:
    for uRow in uCur:            # iterate over every row in your feature class
        uRow[0] = 0              # initialize to 0
        for Value in uRow[1:]:   # iterate everything after the first
            uRow[0] += Value     # add each value in turn
    uCur.updateRow(uRow)         # update the values in the feature class
```

I am using [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to get all the field names, it's a concept that beginners find a bit difficult but well worth the effort to understand how list comprehension works. You might need to do some error handling in your addition for null values or (even worse) strings.

Comment: I'd use uRow[0] = sum(uRow[1:])  to make a code 2 lines shorter.